# R: как измерить объем переданных через интернет данных в рамках одной сессии?

Tags: сессия, r

Есть ли простой способ (в идеале, вида `package::function`), чтобы измерить, какой объем данных был передан (скачан и/или загружен) в течение R сессии?

Мне ничего кроме прямолинейного варианта парсить `.Rhistory` в голову не приходит. Нагуглить решение не получилось.

---

Примечание: [задал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975404/r-session-measure-amount-of-data-downloaded) этот вопрос на английском SO - наткнулся на непонимание. Буду очень признателен за помощь!

Comment: Не слышал о существовании чего-то подобного в R. Я думаю, вам проще использовать спец. софт для этой цели с возможностью фильтрации по процессу (в данном случае R или rsession).

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov спасибо за ответ! Я уже тоже склоняюсь к подобному мнению - использовать сторонний софт. Странно, начинал я поиск с уверенностью, что найду что-то а-ля `sessionInfo()` со всей релевантной информацией об обмене данными за сессию посредством интернета. Я [поспрашивал](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public) в R чате, а также запили issue разработчикам [`checkpoint`](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/checkpoint/issues/212). Посмотрим, что из этого выйдет.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте порыть в этом направлении:

```
library(curl)
req <- curl_fetch_memory("https://stepic.org/favicon.ico")
parse_headers(req$headers)
parse_headers(req$headers)[5]
```